# How to MySQL two dates sum and compare with current timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I want to sum and compare dates with current time and logic I applied is below:

```
SELECT 
    (TIMESTAMP(field1) + TIMESTAMP(field2)) AS t,  
    TIMESTAMP(NOW()) AS tt 
FROM
    table1
```

But it is not working properly.comparison gives wrong results or empty.I thought it is timezone issue and I have set the common timezone for both PHP and MySQL.

Is there any other way to sum two dates and compare?

I want to compare like below in where

```
(TIMESTAMP(field1) + TIMESTAMP(field2)) <  TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) )
```

OR query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (TIMESTAMP(field1) + TIMESTAMP(field2))  as t , TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) )
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is your comparison?

Comment: Show some example data, and expected result.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: I have updated above.

Comment: What is in `field1` and `field2`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: field1 is datetime and field2 is time.

Comment: From the docs *"The DATETIME type is used for values that contain **both date and time parts**. "*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `where` condition doesn't make sense and is syntactically wrong as seen below

```
where (TIMESTAMP(field1) + TIMESTAMP(field2))  as t , TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) )
```

It should rather be

```
where TIMESTAMP(field1, field2) < TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

You can pass both expression `field1` and `field2` to `TIMESTAMP` function. See [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)

Comment: Can you post some sample data and don't use that + rather try the corrected one I posted in answer.